# How to convert java stream collect to scala

Tags: java, scala

Java code

```
objRefs = objRefs.stream().filter(objRef -> DataUtil.isNotEmpty(objRef)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

How to convert it to scala?
Following code compile error

```
objRefs = objRefs.stream().filter(objRef => DataUtil.isNotEmpty(objRef)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet::new` is not valid scala. Do you mean to call the constructor of LinkedHashSet? If so, use `new LinkedHashSet(_)`

The solution you've chosen is translating java to scala. If you do that, there is little value in using scala at all, and you might as well use java.

A more idiomatic solution would be

`objRefs.stream().filter(DataUtil.isNotEmpty).asScala(Set)`